# Python eval(string == string)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, eval

I'm trying to use eval function to read a string and evaluate the content that's inside the string.

```
a = 'red'
b = '=='
c = 'red'
print(eval(a+b+c))
```

it throw me an error

```
NameError: name 'red' is not defined
```

Note: i know it evaluate to red==red and read it as an variable instead of string but dont know how to make it string during eval process i.e 'red'=='red'

Than i tried with ast

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(a+b+c)
```

but gives an error :

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Compare object at 0x035706F0>
```

Than i tried `ast.parse`
but i dont want to write seperate function/method based on operators
if it can be done with `eval` only function/method

Any advice or links to useful resources would be appreciated.

Comment: You should prolly read up how `eval` works and/or try `red == red` as the first expression in your terminal.

Comment: @Moses "Note: i know it evaluate to red==red and read it as a variable instead of a string"

Comment: @pycoder "and/or"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = "'red'"
c = "'red'"
```

A more general way to do this is using `repr`:

```
repr('red') # -> "'red'"
repr('"blue"') # -> '\'"blue"\'' (this does actually evaluate to '"blue"')
```

Comment: Good call on using `repr`

Answer (score 2):

While what you are doing is a terrible idea and can be done in other ways, you need to add quotes within your string:

```
a = '\'red\''
b = ' == '
c = '\'red\''
```

OR

```
a = '"red"'
b = ' == '
c = '"red"'
```

OR

```
a = "'red'"
b = ' == '
c = "'red'"
```

Any of these should work. The choice is yours based on the type of quotes you want and the amount of escaping you are willing to do.

On a side note, you don't need to use `eval` for your particular example:

```
a == c
```

will give the result of the eval. If you are worried about not knowing the operator, use a `dict` and the `operator` module:

```
import operator

ops = {
    '==': operator.eq,
    '<': operator.lt,
    '<=': operator.le,
    ...
}
ops[b](a, c)
```

Comment: this is the right way to do this. Do a lookup of the correct operator and, y'know, *operate* with it.

Comment: I know i can do a==b directly too , this is just an example i am working on expression evaluator, l so i cant know left and right value,

Comment: @Vaibhav. In that case you should still consider using tools other than `eval`. `ast` is probably going in the right direction. Take a look at all that it makes available to you.

Comment: @Vaibhav. In the meantime, @pycoder's advice about using `repr` will suit your needs.